# Assign number to object in Unity 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to assign a number to objects in Unity 3D and the number should appear on the object. Please, I need help on a code to do this. I have little knowledge of C#, but I have been learning aggressively these days. I will appreciate any help. Thanks. Below is a sample code I assign to each of the object.

```c#
public class NumberHolder : MonoBehaviour 
{
    int myNumber = 0;

    UnityEngine.UI.Text myTextField;

    void Awake() 
    {
         myNumber = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0,100) + 1;
         myTextField = GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Text>();
    }

    void Start() 
    {
        if(myTextField != null) 
        {
            myTextField.text = "" + myNumber;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Include an example of what you have tried in the question and it will be easier for people to point out where you went wrong.

Comment: I just update a code that I think it should work. Thanks

Comment: What is the problem you're getting, exactly? The code above looks working enough to me, except for a few redundancies.

Comment: @SonicBlue22, I want the number to appear on the box or any object type I use.

Comment: If I am not mistaken then maybe having a UI Text component in use, could solve what you desire. the only thing you need to set is the text value of the component.

Comment: are you speaking about either `public int myNumber` or `[SerializedField] private int myNumber` in order to set the value from the inspector? and instead of `"" + myNumber` please use `myNumber.ToString()`! And note that `Start()` will only be executed once .. if you want that updated constantly than you have to put it in `Update()`

Comment: @derHugo i think OP wants `WorldToScreenPosition` to overlay textbox on an object in 3d... just a guess though.

Answer (score 0):

Try the script below. It should contain some tidbits to direct you. A couple things to note: for this script, your object must have a collider (doesn't matter which kind: 2D or 3D). Also, this script displays the object's number only when the mouse is over the object. I could tailor it to always show the object, but I gotta make you work a little. Plus, I think in the long run this will work splendidly for you, as you can dissect it.

I will give you a hint. What's the secret to drawing text at the object's position?

You need to convert the object's world space coordinates, to screen space coordinates and then overlay your text.

Consider the following code blocks.

These methods determine if the `mouseposition` on screen is over the object:

```
private void OnMouseEnter()
{
    isVis = true;       
}

private void OnMouseExit()
{
    isVis = false;        
}
```

These lines draw the objects number at the mouse location:

```
Vector2 mospos = Input.mousePosition;
mospos.y = Screen.height - mospos.y;
if (isVis)
{
    GUI.Box(new Rect(Input.mousePosition.x + 2, Screen.height -
        Input.mousePosition.y + 2, 128, 72),"" + myNumber);
}
```

Full class below. Hope it helps!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class LocalLabelingScript : MonoBehaviour {

Monster beast;

bool isVis = false;
int myNumber;

private void Awake()
{
    myNumber = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0,100) + 1;
}

private void OnGUI()
{
    Vector2 mospos = Input.mousePosition;
    mospos.y = Screen.height - mospos.y;

    if (isVis)
    {
        GUI.Box(new Rect(Input.mousePosition.x + 2, Screen.height - 
            Input.mousePosition.y + 2, 128, 72),"" + myNumber);
    }

    private void OnMouseEnter()
    {
        isVis = true;
    }

    private void OnMouseExit()
    {
        isVis = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have few knowledge of C#. It might be kinda hard for me to come up with the code, but I will play around with it. Thanks